# Limiting S3 bucket access to users within one account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an IAM user that has full S3 access (i.e. can perform any S3 actions on any S3 resource within the AWS account). This user has created a bucket and put some files in it. The bucket has a policy which just contains an Allow rule that grants access to a different IAM user, in the same AWS account. Public access is turned off for the bucket.

Should the first user be able to access objects in this bucket? If so, is that because they created the bucket, or because they're in the account that owns the bucket? Is it possible to limit access to a bucket for users within the same AWS account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 is one of the few services with resource policies, in this case they are called bucket policies.

A user in the same account has access to a (S3) resource if

- nothing explicitly denies the access AND
- either the bucket policy grants access OR the user / entity has a policy attached that grants access

If you wanted to restrict a bucket to a single user / entity you would

- need to write a bucket policy that specifies that using a `Deny` statement for every user except the target one AND
- either add a statement to the bucket policy or a policy attached to the user / entity granting access to the bucket.

The standard doc for understanding policy evaluation logic is [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html). There are other, more complicated ways to achieve your goal using e.g. permission boundaries and SCPs but they are probably overkill in your situation.

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks. So if all users in an account have `s3:*` access to all resources, a bucket policy that grants access to one of those users is redundant - is this correct?

Comment: @GrahamClark yes, that would be redundant.

Comment: **Side-note:** Be careful when granting `s3:*` access. This also gives the users permission to delete objects, delete buckets, and make objects/buckets public (could be embarrassing if they contain confidential data).